# code mutator for Ruby other than heckle?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, unit-testing

I am working with ruby 1.8, rails 3.1 and rspec 2.7

I am trying to make very good tests, I want to try one of those code mutation tools. I have only found Heckle but it seems to be very outdated and I am having a hard time to make it work with my setup.
Is there any other code mutation tool for Ruby out there? 
or 
Is there any other way get some automatic feedback on the quality of tests? (excluding coverage)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are there any good mutation testing tools for ruby 1.9 and RSpec2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8252826/are-there-any-good-mutation-testing-tools-for-ruby-1-9-and-rspec2)

Comment: I'll be happy enough if someone answer that other question (although I am not using ruby 1.9).

Comment: What problems are you having with heckle, apart from it only working on 1.8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I rewrote [mutant](https://github.com/mbj/mutant) from scratch.

Usage instructions can be found in the Readme on Github. Mutant targets MRI and RBX on 2.0 / 2.1 / 2.2 mode. It currently can only kill mutations using rspec3, but other killers are possible.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Mutant](https://github.com/txus/mutant). It is a rewrite of heckle built on top of Rubinius.

Comment: JFYI: It not bound to rubinius anymore for years. Works with MRI and rubinuus.